# Find the number of all possible valuations that will satisfy given expression.

Tags: combinatorics, logic

This part concerns the 256 possible truth valuations of the following eight propositional letters A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H. For each of the following expressions, say how many of the 256 valuations satisfy the expression, and briefly explain your reasoning. For example, the expression D is satisfied by half of the valuations, that is 128 of the 256, since for each valuation that makes D true there is a matching valuation that makes D false.

(a) A ∧ B

(b) (A ∨ B) ∧ C

(c) (A → B) → C

(d)
(A → B)∧(B → A)∧(C → D)∧(D → E)∧(E → F )∧(F → G)∧(G → H)

(e)
(A → B) ∧ (B → A) ∧ (C → D) ∧ (D → C)
∧ (E → F ) ∧ (F → G) ∧ (G → H)

(f)
(H → A)∧(A → B∧C)∧(B∨C → D)∧(A → E)∧(E → F )∧(F → G)∧(G → H)

How can I tackle this question? There is another question ([How many valuations of these literals satisfy this expression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020335/how-many-valuations-of-these-literals-satisfy-this-expression)) that explains how to find the answer for expressions like (d) and (e) but I can't find the right answer for (b) (c) and (f). Any advice would help me a lot.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure for D, there are $128$ combinations? In order to show this, you must show that for every validation that makes D true, there is a matching validation that makes it false AND **for every validation that makes D false, there is a matching validation that makes it true**. I'm not sure that the latter is actually true.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is right. However, it's not me who wrote the question.

Comment: I'm getting $14$ possibilities. Either $A$ and $B$ are $(\bot, \bot)$ or $(\top, \top)$ and then there are $7$ possibilities for $C-H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Both $A$ and $B$ must be true. The probability of this happening is $\frac 1 4$, so we have $\frac {256}{4}=64$ possibilities.

b) The probability of $A \vee B$ being true is $\frac 3 4$ and the probability of $C$ being true is $\frac 1 2$, so we have $\frac 3 4\cdot \frac 1 2\cdot 256=96$ possibilities.

c) Either $A \implies B$ is false OR $A \implies B$ is true and $C$ is true.

- $A \implies B$ is false has a $\frac 1 4$ probability of being true.
- $A \implies B$ is true has $\frac 3 4$ probability of being true and $C$ has a $\frac 1 2$ probability of being true, so this case gives us a $\frac 1 8$ probability.

Thus, there are $\left(\frac 1 4+\frac 3 8\right)256=160$ possibilities here.

d) We have $A \iff B$, so either $(A,B)=(\bot,\bot)$ or $(A,B)=(\top,\top)$. Now, we can find the possibilities for $C-H$ and multiply that by $2$. By $G \implies H$, either $G$ is false or $G$ and $H$ are true.

- If $G$ is false, then either $H$ is true or $H$ is false, but by contrapositives, $C-G$ must also be false, so there are $2$ possibilities here.
- If $G-H$ are true, then by $F \implies G$, either $F$ is false, giving us $C-F$ is false by contrapositives and only $1$ possibility, or $F$ is true.
- If $F-H$ are true, then by $E \implies F$, either $E$ is false, giving us $C-E$ is false by contrapositives and only $1$ possibility, or $E$ is true.
- If $E-H$ are true, then by $D \implies E$, either $D$ is false, giving us $C-D$ is false by contrapositives and only $1$ possibility, or $D$ is true.
- If $D-H$ are true, then $C$ can be either true or false, giving us $2$ possibilities.

Thus, we get $7$ possibilities for $C-H$, giving us $7\cdot 2=14$ possibilities overall.

e) Use the example for part d and do something similar here.

f) Notice that because of the ring of implications, if any one of $A,E,F,G,H$ are true, then everything else is true, so that's $1$ possibility. Otherwise, $A,E,F,G,H$ are all false, but by $(B \vee C) \implies D$ we have that $B \vee C$ is false, giving us $2$ possibilities for $D$, or we have that $B \vee C$ is true and $D$ is true, giving us $3$ possibilities for $B \vee C$, so there are $1+2+3=6$ possibilities.

Comment: According to the official solutions, there is 160 possible valuations for (c).

Comment: Note that I have verified Part D and Part F [with a Python program](https://gist.github.com/Noble-Mushtak/89840795c04f75ddaff5338f49359716).

Comment: @jdet $160$ is the correct answer, sorry. I had a typo which led me to getting $224$. You can see my corrected solution above.

Comment: Everything is clear now. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

As a general strategy I'd suggest rewriting the formulas in [disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form).  Once you've done this it will be simple to write down a complete set of sets of values the variables can take to satisfy the formula.  All that's left is to count how big the overlap is.

For instance if a formula in DNF looked like

$(a\wedge b)\vee (b \wedge \neg c)$

your solutions are all valuations such that $a=b=1$ or $b=1, c=0$.

Answer (score 1):

For b and c there are only eight possibilities, so you can just count them.  Also for b, you need $A \vee B$ to be true and $C$ to be true.  $C$ is true half the time.  What fraction of the time is a disjunction true?  For f, if you move $H \rightarrow A$ to the end you have a ring of implications.  That ring is only true if all the propositions are true or all of them are false.  Then just count the rest.

Comment: A disjunction is true for 3/4 of the valuations so we have 192 possible valuations for (A ∨ B) and then 1/2 for the entire expression, which gives 96 satisfying valuations. Is that right?

Comment: I would say the 1/2 comes from C, but that is correcdt

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't precise but this is what I was thinking. Thank you.